# how to concat the attribute names of the parent nodes

Tags: xslt

I have a XML Document like this:

```
<Module Name="DacInPlaceUpgradeLtmTest" Desc="" >
 <TestCase Name="ExecuteInPlaceUpgradeTest">
  <TestCase Name="BugRepro">
   <TestCase Name="295130">
      <Variation Id="1" Desc="Sql - EmptyAlterScript">
      <Variation Id="2" Desc="Sql - EmptyDatabase">
   </TestCase>
  </TestCase>
 </TestCase>
</Module>
```

I use xsl to get a value:

```
ExectionInplaceUPgradeTest BugRepro 295130
```

by using following template:

```
 <xsl:template match="TestCase//Variation">
    <xsl:for-each select="..@Name">
```

Today, I can only get 295130, I wonder how can I get all Attribtes of the parent nodes which is TestCase.

Comment: Seems you are only searching for a simple XPath. See my answer.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two complete, short and easy solutions (XSLT 1.0, and XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0).

Answer (score 3):

> *I wonder how can I get all Attributes of the parent nodes which is TestCase*

You might need the XPath `ancestor-or-self` axis:

```
ancestor-or-self::TestCase/@Name
```

> *how to concat the attribte names of the parent nodes*

It really depends on the template context and on the code you are already working on. taking as a reference your fragment, I would write better:

```
<xsl:template match="TestCase[Variation]">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::TestCase/@Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will print the wanted string starting from the `TestCase` node which has a  `Variation` node as a child.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="Variation[@Id = 1]">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="printName"
   select="ancestor::TestCase"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TestCase" mode="printName">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Module Name="DacInPlaceUpgradeLtmTest" Desc="" >
    <TestCase Name="ExecuteInPlaceUpgradeTest">
        <TestCase Name="BugRepro">
            <TestCase Name="295130">
                <Variation Id="1" Desc="Sql - EmptyAlterScript"/>
                <Variation Id="2" Desc="Sql - EmptyDatabase"/>
            </TestCase>
        </TestCase>
    </TestCase>
</Module>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
ExecuteInPlaceUpgradeTest BugRepro 295130
```

**II. XPath 2.0/XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
//TestCase[Variation]
       /ancestor-or-self::TestCase
          /@Name/string(.)
```

**The above XPath 2.0 expression when evaluated on the above XML document produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
ExecuteInPlaceUpgradeTest BugRepro 295130
```

**It can be used in the following XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "//TestCase[Variation]
       /ancestor-or-self::TestCase
          /@Name/string(.)
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```